# Get the time difference between the first and last row

Tags: sql-server, datediff, date-difference

My table structure is like this

```
id date         Time                userid

17  2017-01-22  05:08:09.0000000    836232017
16  2017-01-22  05:08:05.0000000    836232017
11  2017-01-22  05:06:40.0000000    836232017
10  2017-01-22  05:06:38.0000000    836232017
7   2017-01-22  05:06:31.0000000    836232017
```

I need to get the time difference between the first and last value for the corresponding userid and date. 
Eg: the datediff for the userid 836232017 is between '05:08:09.0000000' and 
'05:06:31.0000000'. Please provide a solution for this.

Comment: I tried, but it takes several steps. is it possible to do the same in a single step. i am looking for that

Comment: Check this post on DBA SE - https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/28482/4113

Comment: i tried like 'SELECT DATEDIFF(SECOND, MIN(times), MAX(times))
FROM table'

Comment: @DeepuT add `GROUP BY userid` to your query

Comment: @TriV Thanks for the information

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT userid, 
DATEADD(SECOND, - DATEDIFF(SECOND, MAX(times), MIN(times)), @null) 
FROM table
group by userid
```

or this

```
SELECT userid, 
DATEDIFF(SECOND, Min(times), Max(times)) 
FROM table
group by userid
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
Datediff (day,
(SELECT TOP(1) Date from dbo.YourTable),
(SELECT TOP(1) Date from dbo.YourTable ORDER BY id DESC))
```

So instead of day you can select minutes or hours or whatever, see on this link:
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff.asp

the only thing you have to add is the `WHERE ID= the ID` you want to select and the corresponding date, like this:

```
SELECT
Datediff (minute,
(SELECT TOP(1) Time from dbo.YourTable WHERE userID=123 AND date='yourdate'),
(SELECT TOP(1) Time from dbo.YourTable WHERE userID=123 AND date='yourdate' ORDER BY Time DESC))
```

instead of 123 you specify the ID you are looking for